# laggy typing when binding a text input to compute a filtered list in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application in which I have an input bound to property `query`. There is a computed property `filteredRecords` that uses `query` to filter the `model` to build an array of records for display. The model contains a large number of records so there is some lag in the filtering process. Typing into the search bar is also laggy. It seems that the re-rendering of the list is getting in the way of text being rendered into the search bar.

The computed property is implemented with [ember-cli-filter-by-query](https://github.com/lazybensch/ember-cli-filter-by-query). Below are my controller properties, the implementation of `computedFilterByQuery` is [here](https://github.com/lazybensch/ember-cli-filter-by-query/blob/master/addon/index.js) and [here](https://github.com/lazybensch/ember-cli-filter-by-query/blob/master/addon/util/filter.js):

```
// in controller...
mArray: function() {
  return this.get('model').toArray();
}.property('model'),

filteredRecords: computedFilterByQuery(
  'mArray', 'key', 'query'
).readOnly(),
```

Is there a way to give the search bar "priority" such that typing into it is always smooth, even if the list takes a second or two to update?

Comment: Can you post your computed property code for `filteredRecords`?  Out of curiosity, roughly how many records are there?

Comment: @rog Updated my post, and there are about 800 records.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debounce to your filter so it isn't immediately trying to filter on each change of query? I noticed a similar issue and had success with that approach.

Comment: @Dhaulagiri Thanks, I haven't tried that -- I wasn't familiar with debouncing, but I looked it up and, though not *ideal* (I feel like the function call should not actually need to be delayed), it looks like it should work. If you add an answer showing how to modify the code I posted to debounce it, I'll accept your answer.